# Problema de lentidão com CAST em consulta

Tags: mysql

Preciso de uma ajuda numa conversão de dados que imagino que seja o problema de lentidão em uma consulta minha. Estou usando MySQL 5.6. Na segunda consulta abaixo, no retorno da variável MRESULT, quando uso o valor de `@CALL_ID_DC` como parâmetro, a consulta roda bem rápido. Quando uso à própria variável `@CALL_ID_DC`, a consulta roda muito lenta. O campo `idCall` é um VARCHAR(255).

Como devo proceder para corrigir esse problema?

```
SET @CALL_ID_DC = (
                             SELECT DC.CallId AS idCall
                             FROM TABELA_DC DC
                             WHERE 
                                DC.Seq = 370065764
                        );

-- @CALL_ID_DC => está com valor '12345'


SET @MRESULT = (
                        SELECT C.idCall FROM TABELA_C C
                        WHERE
                            C.idCall = @CALL_ID_DC -- Usando assim, fica lenta a consulta
                            -- C.idCall = '12345' -- Usando assim, a consulta fica rápida
                        LIMIT 1
                    );
```

Já tentei fazer o CAST da variável `@CALL_ID_DC` para CHAR, mas não alterou o comportamento da consulta.

Comment: Já resolvi. Substitui o `=` por `like` na segunda consulta. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Se o seu banco de dados estiver configurado como InnoDB. Você poderia criar uma INDEX para tabela/campo. Sendo assim o banco de dados irá indexar a tabela e as consultas filtrando aquele/aqueles campos ficariam mais rápidas.

Obs: Essa diretriz é especialmente importante para tabelas do InnoDB, onde a chave primária determina o layout físico das linhas no arquivo de dados.

> CREATE INDEX permite adicionar índices a tabelas existentes.
>
> Ex: CREATE INDEX idx_CLIENTES_CODIGO ON CLIENTES(Codigo);

Normalmente é usado para otimizar consultas.

Segue um link para leitura [link](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3620/indices-mysql-otimizacao-de-consultas.aspx)

Comment: Já resolvi. Substitui o `=` por `like` na segunda consulta. Também não posso incluir índices nas minhas tabelas. Obrigado.